# Cannot implement login in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, authentication, html

So, I have followed the tutorial for implementing simple login page over here https://varuntayur.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/session-management-in-gwt/

I tried communicating on the page itself, the author has been very helpful, but up to certain point.

The code is pretty long, so I've uploaded it here:
http://1drv.ms/1GZQqFV

Please be so kind to check it out.

The error displayed is the following:

```
[WARN] 404 - POST /atlas_emergency_status_page/LoginService (127.0.0.1) 1405 bytes
Request headers
  Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
  Connection: keep-alive
  Content-Length: 200
  X-GWT-Module-Base: http://127.0.0.1:8888/atlas_emergency_status_page/
  X-GWT-Permutation: 512BC5E71D8D41DD923CAA7193842B68
  Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8888
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
  Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8
  Accept: */*
  Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/ATLAS_Emergency_Status_Page.html
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-CH;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4,ka;q=0.2,ru;q=0.2

Response headers
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
  Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
  Content-Length: 1405
```

**EDIT**

I heva found the error, in web.xml I mapped servlet as LoginServiceImpl, had to be LoginService.

But now, I have another problem, on clicking the login button, nothing happens and no error is displayed, which is even worse...

What could be the problem?

**EDIT 2**

I have added the logger to be able to better understand what's happening.

Here is the output of logger:

```
Wed Nov 04 17:11:44 GMT+100 2015 logger1 INFO: enbl = false
Wed Nov 04 17:11:44 GMT+100 2015 logger1 INFO: enbl = false
Wed Nov 04 17:11:44 GMT+100 2015 logger1 INFO: No sessionID
Wed Nov 04 17:11:46 GMT+100 2015 logger1 INFO: Called login
Wed Nov 04 17:11:46 GMT+100 2015 logger1 INFO: Configured login dialog box
Wed Nov 04 17:11:47 GMT+100 2015 logger1 INFO: username: password:
Wed Nov 04 17:11:47 GMT+100 2015 logger1 INFO: Success
Wed Nov 04 17:11:47 GMT+100 2015     com.google.gwt.logging.client.LogConfiguration SEVERE: (TypeError)     __gwt$exception: <skipped>: Cannot read property 'allowNestedValues' of     nullcom.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) __gwt$exception:     <skipped>: Cannot read property 'allowNestedValues' of null
   at Unknown.$get(atlas_emergency_status_page-0.js@18:2152)
   at Unknown.$getLoggedIn(atlas_emergency_status_page-0.js@36:2227)
   at Unknown.$onSuccess_0(atlas_emergency_status_page-0.js@88:1182)
   at Unknown.onSuccess_0(atlas_emergency_status_page-0.js@3:1213)
   at Unknown.onResponseReceived(atlas_emergency_status_page-0.js@34:15260)
   at Unknown.$fireOnResponseReceived(atlas_emergency_status_page-0.js@14:7513)
   at Unknown.onReadyStateChange(atlas_emergency_status_page-0.js@5:7718)
   at Unknown.<anonymous>(atlas_emergency_status_page-0.js@13:18406)
   at Unknown.apply_0(atlas_emergency_status_page-0.js@23:3688)
   at Unknown.entry0(atlas_emergency_status_page-0.js@16:3755)
```

It seems to go into error after calling

```
public void onSuccess(UserDTO result) {

                            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Success");
```

and somewhere on this line I would say...
                                logger.log(Level.INFO, "username from UserDTO: " + result.getName());

```
                            if (result.getLoggedIn()) {
```

Again, sorry for newbie questions, but this is way over my level...

Comment: for me this looks like some error in your userdto...because the RPC is working properly and returning the correct value.

Comment: @Tobika, I've updated the original question with logger output